# COMponents mscomctl.ocx, mscomct2.ocx, mswinsck.ocx: set off Kill-Bit programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba, registry, activexobject

On Windows 7, the COMponents listed in the title seem by default to have the "killbit" set to COMPAT_EVIL_DONT_LOAD (compare [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768234.aspx)), that is, their *Compatibility Flags* in *HKLM\SW\IE\ActiveX Compatibility\{<CLSID>}\* seem to be set to that value by default:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility\{B09DE715-87C1-11D1-8BE3-0000F8754DA1}]
"Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000400
```

When I set the value to 0 (that's what [Nirsoft's ActiveX Compatibility Manager](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/acm.html) does when "activating" a COMponent), everything works fine.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\ActiveX Compatibility\{B09DE715-87C1-11D1-8BE3-0000F8754DA1}]
"Compatibility Flags"=dword:00000000
```

But this is just a GUI solution for one workstation. To deploy our software, I need a safe and stable procedure (script or tool) to ship with our software, that not only sets the "killbit" to 0 or deletes the registry entry (which procedure should be preferred?), but checks the situation before and does nothing if nothing is necessary. Preferably, the solution would just be passed over a file name or a list of files and proceeds everything else necessary on its own.

This is the point where the bigger questions begin:

- Regarding COM objects, the registry is queried by CLSID, not by ocx file name (that is the *InProcServer32* entry in the Windows registry) nor by *(VersionIndependent)ProgID* (*HKLM\Software\Classes\CLSID\{<CLSID>}\*). Do you know a method, i.e., a batch / (PowerShell) script / tool / whatever to query the CLSIDs related to an ocx file or at least the ProgID radical?
- I understand the CLSID is constant in Windows 2000 up to 7?
- [SlayOCX.vbs](http://msinfluentials.com/blogs/jesper/archive/2006/09/29/Set-KillBit-on-Arbitrary-ActiveX-Controls-with-Group-Policy.aspx) seems to be a low level approach that, called as a group policy as described in [SlayOCX.vbs](http://msinfluentials.com/blogs/jesper/archive/2006/09/29/Set-KillBit-on-Arbitrary-ActiveX-Controls-with-Group-Policy.aspx) and [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/bradley/archive/2007/11/27/killbit-anyone.aspx), could work as a network-wide solution. But: It's a vbs, switched off in some environments. Furthermore, I will end up with quite a list of CLSIDs to be checked by this script. Wrapped e.g. in a batch I will probably not be able to have it deployed by the customers' admins in the described way, but rather by logon script or runonce key in the registry or something -- not very elegant. So what would you suggest? I'd prefer a solution (a tool, a new group policy in 7 I don't know yet, a more sophisticated script with less dependency on system and security configuration issues, ...) that makes the first informational questions superfluous.

Comment: Get rid of the dependencies on third-party components. It's by far the best practice for reliable distribution. And, yes, that means no treeview control, but the functionality of a treeview can be replicated with native Access controls. It just won't be as spiffy. And, yes, I think it's ridiculous that Access has no native treeview after all these years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CLSID Registry Scanner (COM/ActiveX)](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic61879.html)

is my answer to my own question. It's working for now, that's important for me now. It would be a moot discussion if it was not better to rewrite or at least refurbish the program, or both independently, and get rid of old hats. Would be moot because I do not make our budget decisions.

Answer (score 0):

You want to expose your clients knowingly to security vulnerabilities? I am not a lawyer, but...

According to [**this post**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708), the files mentioned are "Supported Runtime Files to Distribute with Your Application", you just need to update to the latest version.

Another post details the necessary steps (probably for an older update, but still it should get you started):   [**Clickety**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2009/06/05/visual-basic-6-controls-stop-working-after-security-advisory-960715.aspx)

Comment: You just had a very rough look on my post, aeeh?

Comment: How so? As I understand, you are trying to reset the killbit without changing the software or installation. (Maybe I had a rough *day* with people thinking safety is for sissies.)

Comment: The libraries listed in the articles are not alleged to be malicious per se, but are only candidates to be abused or replaced by malicious software and thus subject to setting a killbit or not. mscomctl.ocx is shipped with Windows 7, in my understanding Windows is responsible for it being up-to-date. I will test most current versions of the mxcomct2.ocx and mswinsck.ocx with our software, thank you for your hint. Chances are that this is not the solution anyway, since sys libs are affected as well. I may not vote you down, but please feel your "answer" (-> a comment) being voted down by me.

Comment: I don't think security is for sissies. And I am not the one who decides, just the dependent supporter and programmer who needs to get along with a software he didn't design and may not change in principle. But I don't think that your classification of the legacy libraries being vulnaribilities in themselves is right, so I would not easily decide to rewrite several ten thousand lines of code and change in forms and such just because some legacy but reliable libraries are not loved by M$ any longer.

Comment: It's not my classification, your OP just comes across like someone who doesn't care, and doesn't consider fixing the code instead of working around issues. Please accept my apologies if that is not the case.

Comment: Of course your apologies are accepted. Not, that is not the case. I just concentrated on programmer's questions (I am on a programmers' platform, right? ;-) ) and did not start the (interesting and useful) discussion about the security aspects of ActiveX, M$ business behavior and that all "political" field. In principle, I think you are right, but as to the details of my problem here I think it's not that clear what is best or necessary. And my judgement would not be of interest for anyone anyway.

Answer (score 0):

With the exception of the Treeview replacement code or API calls can be found for most usages of these OCXs.  Apparently there was some German commented API code available for purchase years ago for the treeview.   All these OCXs are is a wrapper for the API calls anyhow.

See the [Calendar Tips page](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/calendars.htm) at my website

The mswinsck is a bit trickier and I don't have a URL for that one.  However I'm sure there is VB6 code that can be found that will work quite nicely in VBA.

Blog posting - [An older version of MSCOMM32.OCX has had the "kill bit" flag set.](http://msmvps.com/blogs/access/archive/2009/06/14/an-older-version-of-mscomm32-ocx-has-had-the-quot-kill-bit-quot-flag-set.aspx)  Although you don't mention this one.

Comment: This is no answer to my question. It's an interesting comment, and I appreciate to know that. I already said that it does not matter if I agree or not to your or peterchen's arguments, my task is to get the current solution working.

Comment: In my opinion spending the extra time to remove all possible Microsoft OCX dependencies is the best solution because you'll never have this problem again.  And installation of your software is easier.